# What's the secret of high performance animation of GSAP?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I am using [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)(JavaScript) which has high animation performance. I am interested in what has happened behind its unbelievable performance. How does it work? How to improve my JavaScript skill of writing animation?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Sorry for my poor English, feel free to correct my grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is freely [available at GitHub](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/). Why not just have a look how they do it?